# Conditionally print subsection in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I've ported from PowerPoint my university's template in Beamer, and  added some code to display sections (and subsections when they exists) in the header.

This is the code snippet I've put in the `headline` template for this purpose:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.6\paperwidth,ht=0.1\beamer@PoliMI@headheight]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\par%
    \vfill\strut\insertsectionhead%
    \ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else%
    ~--~\insertsubsectionhead%
    \fi%
    \strut\par%
\end{beamercolorbox}\\%
```

However, when "exiting" from subsection (issuing `\subsection*{}`), the dash after the section name is still printed.

How can I test if the subsection name is void?
As an alternative, how can I make `\insertsubsection` empty?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}\normalfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.6\paperwidth,ht=0.016\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
    \par\vfill\strut\insertsectionhead%
    \ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else~--~\insertsubsectionhead%
    \fi\strut\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
 \section{aaa}
  \begin{frame}~\end{frame}
  \subsection{bbb}
   \begin{frame}~\end{frame}
  \subsection*{}
   \begin{frame}~\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the third frame, only "aaa" must show up, and not "aaa -".

**UPDATE**: If subsection is not yet defined, `\insertsubsection` is empty, whereas if a `\subsection*{}` is issued, the macro is expanded in `\expandafter \hyperlink \subsectionlink`, either the subsection is empty (`\insertsubsectionhead` expands to `\hyperlink {Navigation\the \c@page }{}`) or not (`\insertsubsectionhead` expands to `\hyperlink {Navigation\the \c@page }{bbb}` in the second frame).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thanks for posting the problem code snippets.  However you should _also_ post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  It is still going to be useful in testing that a proposed solution actually worked.

Comment: @PeterGrill: please see edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have replaced the code snippet with

```
\ifx\insertsubsection\empty\else%
 \ifdefempty{\subsecname}{\relax}{%
  ~--~\insertsubsectionhead%
 }%
\fi
```

and IT WORKS!!!
Unfortunately needs the `etoolbox` package to be loaded...

**EDIT:**

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\subsecname\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\else%
 ~--~\insertsubsectionhead%
\fi%
```

also works and does not require `etoolbox`.
I don't know if this is the "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but I had issues with the 2nd solution of @Astrinus and wanted to share it nonetheless.

`\subsecname` is not deleted by default when a new section is created. Replacing it with `\insertsubsectionhead` worked to solve it for me.

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\else%
        - \insertsubsectionhead%
        \fi%
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with recognizing end of subsection by:

```
\ifx\insertsubsection\empty
```

Limiting the SubSection in braces made it working:

```
{
\subsection{SubSection Title}
<subsection frames>
}
<other frames>
```

The condition correctly differed between frames inside and outside that SubSection